# Unable to install Google cloud tool for eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

It is showing below, please someone help me out how can I resolve this issue.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.8.5.202108061424 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group 1.8.5.202108061424)
Missing requirement: Cloud Tools for Eclipse App Engine Local Server 0.1.0.202108052157 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.localserver 0.1.0.202108052157) requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.servlet 2.5.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:

Comment: Does in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03) fix your issue (the latest release 2022-06 does not contain the `javax.servlet` bundle anymore)?

Comment: Thank you so much @howlger it worked:)
But why 2022-06 release does not contain javax.servlet?

Comment: No plugin/bundle itself, that is part of the 2022-06 release, requires the `javax.servlet` plugin/bundle to work. But I don't know from which plugin it was required in the releases before. Maybe by [Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) which is not part of 2022-06 anymore.

Comment: Yes, it was required by Mylyn which is not part of the 2022-06 release anymore (see `javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016.jar` [here](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/drops/3.25.2/v20200831-1956/plugins/)). Therefore adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest`](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest) would have worked also.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.8.5 requires the `javax.servlet` bundle/pluing, which was part of earlier Eclipse IDE releases, but is no longer part of the 2022-06 release (as [Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) is no longer part of the of the 2022-06 release).

As solution, in **preferences *Install/Update > Available Software Sites*** add the update site [**`https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest`**](https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest).