# Error installing Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse: Missing javax.annotation dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am encountering an issue while attempting to install the Google Cloud Platform plugin for Eclipse. The installation process fails with the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.10.1.202306072020 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group 1.10.1.202306072020)
  Missing requirement: Cloud Tools For Eclipse App Engine Libraries Management 0.1.0.202108052157 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.libraries 0.1.0.202108052157) requires 'osgi.bundle; javax.annotation 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Cloud Tools for Eclipse GPE Migration Support for App Engine Project Conversion 0.1.0.202108052157 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.compat 0.1.0.202108052157)
    To: java.package; com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.libraries 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.10.1.202306072020 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group 1.10.1.202306072020)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.compat [0.1.0.202108052157,0.1.0.202108052157]
```

It seems that the installation process is failing due to a missing dependency `(javax.annotation 0.0.0)` required by the `Cloud Tools for Eclipse App Engine Libraries Management component`.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Updating Eclipse to the latest version.
- Clearing the Eclipse cache and retrying the installation.
- Attempting to install manually by downloading the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace and the Google Cloud Tools website.

I've also tried this solution but it didn't worked.
[Unable to install Google cloud tool for eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73004696/unable-to-install-google-cloud-tool-for-eclipse-ide)

Comment: In the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_, does adding the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-09`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-09) help? In `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest` currently alias for `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-12` the bundle/plugin `javax.annotation` is not contained anymore.

Comment: No it didn't worked.

Comment: When it didn't worked, then probably for other reasons. Please update your question with the error message you get with the `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-09` containing `javax.annotation`.

Comment: I'm getting the error I've mentioned

Comment: When you install it via _Help > Install New Software..._ make sure the _Contact all update sites during install to find required software_ checkbox is checked. You cannot downloading the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace as it does not host any plugins itself (it is just a catalog). Please tell the exact way you used for installing and the update site URL you used. Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with `eclipse.buildId=` and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something

Comment: It was not working so I downgraded Eclipse to 2021-03 version and then it got installed.

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading Eclipse to version **2021-03**, I attempted the installation of the Google Cloud Platform plugin again, and this time it installed without encountering the javax.annotation dependency error.

This workaround might not be ideal for everyone, but it resolved the installation issue in my case.